# Representing a binary tree in an SQL table using foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, binary-tree

This is an example of a representation of a binary tree in an SQL table:

```
     A                                 node  | parent
    / \                                  A   |  NULL
   /   \                                 B   |   A
  /     \                                C   |   A
 B       C                               D   |   B
 |      / \                              E   |   C
 |     /   \                             F   |   C
 D     E    F
```

As you can see the table tree has two columns: node which is a primary key, and parent which is foreign key. In each node is stored a reference to its parent node. 
I want to define the same tree but this time using children, each node should reference its children instead.
Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Well, you could just rename column `node` to `child` and column `parent` to `node`, or I am missing something?

Comment: @GMB It would be awkward to store a single-node tree, consisting of the root `node` but no `child` - the only case where you'd store a no-child explicitly.

Comment: @Bergi - That is why the current implementation is optimal. In fact *I want to have children instead of parents* makes a little sense because a structure is defined by the problem to be solved, not the other way around.

Comment: The question should be: I have a problem (description here) that cannot be solved with the current model. How should I change the model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 2):

You'd have some table with three columns. One for an identifier for the node and two for them of its children. So basically something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE bintree
             (id integer,
              left integer,
              right integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (left)
                          REFERENCES bintree
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (right)
                          REFERENCES bintree
                                     (id));
```

And maybe a check constraint, that checks that `left` isn't equal to `right` and a (constraint) trigger that checks that the thing stays cycle free...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also define the tree in term of arcs by using two tables

For example:

```
     A              Table: Nodes       Table: Arcs
    / \             node               parent  | child
   /   \              A                    A   |   B
  /     \             B                    A   |   C
 B       C            C                    B   |   D
 |      / \           D                    C   |   E
 |     /   \          E                    C   |   F
 D     E    F         F
```

This way the a parent can be related to zero, one, or more children.

The SQL script to do this is:

```
create table nodes (
  id varchar(10) primary key not null
);

create table arcs (
  parent varchar(10) not null,
  child varchar(10) not null,
  constraint uq1 unique (parent, child), -- optional
  foreign key (parent) references nodes (id),
  foreign key (child) references nodes (id)
);
```